# Image compression exception; Failed to allocate a 629749908 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 142MB until OOM

Tags: java, android, image, compression

I have had some problems with the size of the images in my application, so I decided to compress the images, but I get the exception "Failed to allocate a 629749908 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 142MB until OOM". I know that is a memory problem but, what I can do? there are other alternatives?

This is the method I am using

```
private Bitmap checkCompression(Bitmap imageTarget) {
    double width = imageTarget.getWidth();//This has 2448
    double height = imageTarget.getHeight();//This has 3264
    double current = width * height;//Result is 7990272
    int reference = 1800000;
    double percentage = 0;

    if (current > reference) {
        percentage = current / reference;
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageTarget, (int) (width * percentage), (int) (height * percentage), true);
    }

    return imageTarget;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using picasso. It has a very nice way handling images especially the large ones. Take a look [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/) .

Comment: Good to know. Enjoy coding!. (thumbs_up)